# Trying to pass multiple parameters to ajax call fails

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to a JQuery $.ajax function and they appear to be blank when they get to the called web service. If I pass one parameter it seems to get there. The function is:

```
function callGetDataAndUpdateGrid(input, startIndex, maximumRows) {
            var gridRequest = {
                requestGUID: input,
                startIndex: startIndex,
                maximumRows: maximumRows,
            };

            console.log(input);

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/GetContactsDataAndCountbyGUID",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: gridRequest,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    updateGrid(result.Data);
                    updateVirtualItemCount(result.Count);
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
                    console.log("AJAX call failed in callUpdateGrid");
                    console.log(errThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

The input is a JSON string and it comes from the function that calls the above:

```
function pageLoad(sender, eventArgs) {
            var tableView = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
            var input = { "requestGUID": "<%=guid %>" };
            GetDataFromServer(input, 0, tableView.get_pageSize());
        }

        function GetDataFromServer(input, startIndex, maximumRows) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                // dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                       setTimeout(function (inputInner) { GetDataFromServer(inputInner); }, 1000);                    } else {
                        console.log("data returned - calling callUpDateGrid");
                        console.log(input);
                        //Continue as data is ready
                        callGetDataAndUpdateGrid(input, startIndex, maximumRows);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
                    console.log("AJAX call failed in CallIsDataReady");
                    console.log(errThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

The var input = { "requestGUID": "<%=guid %>" }; makes it to the first function where it is logged by the Entity Framework code into the database. On callGetDataAndUpdateGrid function it does not. When I was passing just one parameter (input) it made it there. The EF code logs that it is blank. So how do you pass multiple parameters? Do I have too many variables called input?

BTW, the signature for the WCF web method is:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        // [WebGet]
        public ResultData GetContactsDataAndCountbyGUID(string requestGUID, int startIndex, int maximumRows)
```

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` is incorrect, you aren't sending json to the server. (though this likely won't fix your problem)

Comment: This parameter is JSON var input = { "requestGUID": "<%=guid %>" }; but I guess the rest aren't.

Comment: That's an object, not json.

Comment: ok, how would I pass these three parameters as JSON? Can you show me the code please?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(gridRequest),` and change your `type:` to POST

Comment: That gives me a Method Not Allowed. I guess I'll have change the WCF to a POST but I think GET is required to work with the Telerik code.How do u change [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] to a POST?

Comment: GET is more appropriate for what you are doing, but you can't(or, shouldn't) send json in the request body of a GET request.

Comment: Figured it out but now AJAX call in first function IsDataReady fails wit Internal Error and I didn;t change that